# Homology of a subspace of a $2$-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

In some [homework solutions](http://tarunchitra.com/papers/6510/hw8.pdf#page=3) someone posted online, one of the problems was from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*: computing the homology groups of the space which is the union of the boundary of $I \times I$ along with all the points in $I \times I$ with rational first coordinate.

The author of these homework solutions makes the comment

> Since $X$ is a subspace of a 2-dimensional manifold, all continuous
>   maps $\sigma: \Delta^k \to X$ have the same boundary as the image of a
>   continuous map $\sigma: \Delta^{k-1} \to X$ for $k \geq 2$. Therefore
>   $H_k(X)=0$ for $k \geq 2$.

Can someone explain to me what this might mean (assuming the author is indeed making sense)? I can't seem to understand.

Comment: I don't parse what they're writing. In particular, it sounds to me like their "argument" should apply to show $H_n(X)=0$ whenever $X$ is a subspace of a manifold of dimension $<n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nonsense; I don't know what they're trying to say, and nothing I can imagine they might be saying is a sufficient argument to imply their conclusion.  In fact, the statement that $H_k(X)=0$ for $k>n$ if $X$ is a subset of an $n$-manifold is false in general (though it may be true for $n=2$).  A famous counterexample is the "$n$-dimensional Hawaiian earring" for $n>1$, which has nontrivial homology in infinitely many dimensions despite being a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (namely, the union of infinitely many shrinking $n$-spheres that all meet at a point).  See [this paper of Barratt and Milnor](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/) (the original reference!) for a proof.